# Changing my logo image for mobiles via responsive css

Tags: css

I want to display a different image to my mobile users using CSS only, as i don't have access to the html code.

When on mobile I have added display:none to the header-logo-image img { and then add a background-url to the div which succesfully displays my alternative logo.  The only problem is when i switch to the background image in the div, I lose my link to the homepage that my other img provided.

Is there any way round this so I can get the background image to link? 
Is this where CSS image sprites could come in but use them on the img instead?

```
<div id="header-logo-image">
<a href="http://example.com/folder/">
<img src="http://example.com/folder/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/head-logo.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

To switch logos when on a mobile device this is an option:

**HTML**

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/"></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-brand {
    background: url(PATH_TO_IMG/logo.png);
    width:220px;
    height:65px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        background: url(PATH_TO_IMG}/logo_small.png) no-repeat center;
        width:70px;
    }
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7aptjp44/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Apparently my cellphone is no longer a cellphone when I hold it in portrait mode :-D

Comment: It does that, you can edit the media query to capture this @JanDvorak or just edit the `max-width`

Comment: What about the href url link if I can't get to the html/code?

Comment: @pnumbers What about the `href` link? It'll work like it always has

Answer (score 1):

add in your css

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #logo {
    content: url("http://yourwebsite.com/mobile_logo.png");
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  #logo {
    content: url("http://yourwebsite.com/large_logo.png");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:800px) {
.navbar-brand img { opacity: 0; }
.navbar-brand {
    background: url(PATH_TO_IMG}/logo_small.png) no-repeat center;
    width:200px;
}
}
```

That way I could leave the existing logo CSS and file there.